# Get WooCommerce product permalink by product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks, taxonomy-terms

I have made this code and the variable $link is not returning the product url, instead is returning home url. Please some Help! What I want is to get the product link selecting it by category. The display is like a menu by category but with the link going directly to one product I selected by category.

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $categories= get_terms( 'product_cat', array( 'parent' => 15, 'hide_empty' => false ) );
    foreach($categories as $category): ?>
        <li>
            <div class="grid-subheader">
                <?php 
                    $metaArray = get_option('taxonomy_' . $category->term_id);
                    $productCatMetaTitle = $metaArray['wh_meta_title'];
                    $type = get_term_by( 'id', $category->parent, 'product_cat' );
                    
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type'             => 'product',
                        'post_status'           => 'publish',
                        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
                        'posts_per_page'        => 1,
                        'tax_query'             => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                                'field' => 'term_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
                                'terms'         => $category->term_id,
                                'operator'      => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
                            )
                        )
                    );

                    $products = new WP_Query($args);

                    foreach ($products as $prod){
                        $link = get_the_permalink($prod->ID);   
                    }
                ?>

                <h3><?php echo $productCatMetaTitle; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $category->description; ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
                    <div class="button-menu">
                        <?php //echo $type->name; ?> <?php echo $category->name; ?>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li> 
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following revisited code:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    $category_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'parent' => 15, 'hide_empty' => false ) );

    foreach( $category_terms as $term ) { ?>
        <li>
            <div class="grid-subheader">
            <?php
            $meta  = get_option('taxonomy_' . $term->term_id);
            $title = isset($meta['wh_meta_title']) ? $meta['wh_meta_title'] : '';
            $type  = get_term_by( 'id', $term->parent, $taxonomy );
            $query = get_posts( array(
                'post_type'             => 'product',
                'post_status'           => 'publish',
                'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
                'posts_per_page'        => 1,
                'fields'                => 'ids',
                'tax_query'             => array( array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => array( $term->term_id ),
                ) ),
            ) );

            $product_id = reset($query);
            ?>
                <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
                <?php if ( ! empty($term->description) ) ?>
                    <p><?php echo $term->description; ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($product_id); ?>">
                        <div class="button-menu"><?php echo $term->name; ?></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It work perfectly!!! Nice solution!